# While Loop condition not being checked

Tags: java, eclipse

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class CollatzSequence {
static int pileA = 3;
static int pileB = 3;
static int pileC = 3;

static String choice = "";
static int turn = 1;
static int remove = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int newA = 3;
    int newB = 3;
    int newC = 3;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1: ");
    String p1 = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Player 2: ");
    String p2 = scan.next();

    while (newA != 0 || newB != 0 || newC != 0) {

        if (turn == 1) {
            System.out.println("PileA: " + newA + "PileB: " + newB + "PileC:     " + newC);

            System.out.println("Choose pile " + p1);
            choice = scan.next();
            if (choice.equals("A")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newA = pileA - remove;
                pileA = newA;
                turn = 2;
            }

            if (choice.equals("B")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newB = pileB - remove;
                pileB = newB;
                turn=2;
            }
            if (choice.equals("C")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newC = pileC - remove;
                pileC = newC;
                turn = 2;
            }

        }
        if (turn == 2) {
            System.out.println("PileA: " + newA + "PileB: " + newB + "PileC: " + newC);
            System.out.println("Choose pile " + p2);
            choice = scan.next();
            if (choice.equals("A")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newA = pileA - remove;
                pileA = newA;
                turn = 1;
            }

            if (choice.equals("B")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newB = pileB - remove;
                pileB = newB;
                turn = 1;
            }
            if (choice.equals("C")) {
                System.out.println("Remove how much?");
                remove = scan.nextInt();
                newC = pileC - remove;
                pileC = newC;
                turn = 1;
            }

        }

    }


}
}
```

This should simulate a basic nim game. Players keep removing form the stacks until none are left. Problem is that the loop does not terminate. Though I can't pinpoint it yet I think it's in my visibility modifiers / the fact that the if statements keep going back and forth from turn = 1 to turn=2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I would use:**

```
if(turn == 1){
    ...
}
else{       //for turn ==2
    ...
}
```

Because the problem appears in situation, when after first player move all piles are empty (and You still ask player2 for move, no matter what he chose (!=0) after his move there will be a pile that is not equal to 0, so the statement in while will return true).

**Another method**
Would be to make `while (newA >= 0 || newB >= 0 || newC >= 0)` but then there still might be a one unnecessary move (for player2).

If I missed something, please tell me, but this should work.

Comment: Shouldn't it be while (newA >= 0 && newB >= 0 && newC >= 0) instead of  while (newA >= 0 || newB >= 0 || newC >= 0) , as all the three have to be +ve to proceed.

Comment: Depends on what rules author wants to have, yes or no. If I were him, I would make additional `if`s to check if newX is positive.